# How can I export a vanilla PDF from Acrobat Reader on Mac?

Tags: pdf, adobe

I have a fancy PDF that only opens in Acrobat Reader and I cannot figure out how to export a plain, compatible-with-everything PDF copy of it. There is no option in the print dialog and the "save as" and export options don't give me what I need either (a PDF that opens in everything). I'm not going to sign up for an Adobe account to use their stupid online tools. I need a way to do this locally.

It's doable in Reader for Windows, but not Mac. I kinda hate Adobe these days...

Comment: Actually, it looks like this option has been removed from the current Windows version as well. It used to show "Adobe PDF" as a printer option to print to. Now it's gone.

Comment: What does "fancy" mean here? In order to modify the PDF (not filling out form fields), you will need Acrobat Pro.

Comment: By _fancy_ I mean it has form-changing code and buttons and such. I don't need to change the structure or anything, just create a printable version without all the code and buttons. Ended up having to print through PrimoPDF on Windows. Totally ridiculous.